# UISegmentedControl with Direction or Arrow theme

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, uicontrol

I have implemented **UISegmentedControl** with **Direction** theme using **[BASequenceControl](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/basequencecontrol)** from **cocoacontrols.com**.

I have added **[BASequenceControl.h](http://pastebin.com/Xz6xwyL0)** and **[BASequenceControl.m](http://pastebin.com/r2J4vSVZ)** classes and required images from **[GitHub](https://github.com/dimzzy/BaseAppKit)**

Great. Its working fine for me..However I have a concern with the last segment section tip.

Its displaying the junk space of last segment section.

**Original Screen Shot**

[image]

**I need like this**

[image]

**The code I have Implemented**

```
        #import "BASequenceControl.h"

BASequenceControl *bASequenceControl = [[BASequenceControl alloc] init];                                    
bASequenceControl.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 44);
[bASequenceControl addSegmentWithTitle:@"First" animated:NO];
[bASequenceControl addSegmentWithTitle:@"Second" animated:NO];

bASequenceControl.leftMargin = -22;
bASequenceControl.rightMargin = 0;
bASequenceControl.overlapWidth = 22;

[self.view addSubview:bASequenceControl];
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty simple fix. You will have to edit the BASequenceControl.m file or you can duplicate the class and rename it.

The line that is causing the problem is in `drawRect:` it basically draws the grey arrow across the entire background of the control. Creating that nice gradient in the empty space.

```
[passiveSegmentImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(-passiveSegmentImage.size.width, 0,
                                           w + 2 * passiveSegmentImage.size.width, h)];
```

You can change it to:

```
[passiveSegmentImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                           w, h)];
```

Now you have to tell the control that it should not be opaque. Update the initializers like this.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    _selectedSegmentIndex = -1;
    [self setOpaque:NO];
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        [self setOpaque:NO];
        _selectedSegmentIndex = -1;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is pretty quick and dirty, you could potentially make this settable with a property. Then submit a pull request to BaseAppKit, but I'll leave that to you. Here is a gist that you can copy and paste directly in BASequenceControl.m to fix the overhang.
https://gist.github.com/4632686

Edit: Make sure that you are using `init` as the initializer and then `setFrame:` (I'm not really sure why `initWithFrame:` wasn't overridden in the class.)

```
BASequenceControl *control = [[BASequenceControl alloc] init];
[control setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 40)];
```

[image: Fixed control, green for dramatic effect]

Green background for dramatic effect

Comment: thanks very much for the great fix. After your fix, it shows black color(earlier it was gray). So is there any way to make the empty space (after the last segment) as white color ? if yes,then only it will exactly look like an arrow.because my view background color is white.

Comment: Yep, see the edit regarding `init`. It should be totally transparent, I have tested it and it looks good on my end.

Answer (score 0):

How about to use a mask like this :

[image]

to mask your SegmentedControl

Comment: thanks for your answer . could you please explain in detail ?