# ui segment control images for different image path

Tags: iphone

I want to set image frame in segment control index path and I have googled for that and not get the specific answer to do so. I'm doing

```
[self.segmentedControl setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"popularitem-activee.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [self.segmentedControl setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"popularuserr.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
```

and i want to do so

```
[self.segmentedControl setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:image1 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: what u mean by "set image frame in segment control index path" ?

Comment: i mean first to take image as image1 then set its frame and then load to segment control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't give different frame for each segment, you can give frame for whole segment control.

Comment: sir can i add image like this                      [self.segmentedControl setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:image1 forSegmentAtIndex:0];

Comment: what u want to achieve ? explain in detail..:)

Comment: See whats the scenario i'm working in an application which has a ui with a segment control and building for iphone 5 but the problem is that if I put image in large size it gets over the ui and if small the image gets blurred and the image what i'm using is 280*60 size.

Comment: it will help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514712/uisegmentedcontrol-with-direction-or-arrow-theme